# Vuejs computed ошибка

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Я пытаюсь написать валидации для данных  при регистрации,но возникла проблема с computed,а именно вот код в котором я проверяю валидность данных

```
`computed: 
    {
      check_phone()
      {
        console.log("ef",this.phone)
          if(this.phone == "")
            return  this.valid_phone = null
          if(this.$validator.validate('phone'))
            return this.valid_phone = true
           else
             return this.valid_phone = false
      }
    },`
```

[image: Ошибки]

Если кто-то укажет ошибку или покажет как правильно использовать computed буду благодарен.

Comment: Срабатывает правило, которое запрещает изменять другие свойства внутри `computed` свойств, а конкретнее ругается на такие строки как `return this.valid_phone = null`, где должно быть `return null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

стоит удалить переменную this.valid_phone из data и сделать computed свойство valid_phone

```
  computed: {
    valid_phone()
    {
      if(this.phone == "")
        return  null;
      if(this.$validator.validate('phone'))
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
  }
```

или переписать на watch

```
watch: {
  phone: function (val) {
    if(val == "")
      this.valid_phone = null;
    if(this.$validator.validate('phone'))
      this.valid_phone = true;
    else
      this.valid_phone = false;
  }
}
```